# htaccess trailing slash not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the below code in my htaccess.  The site works fine (ie: no 500 errors) but it is not adding the trailing slash to my URLs:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://staging.foo.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

What do I have wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the order of your rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://staging.foo.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

The reason why it wasn't working was because the routing to `/index.php` rule was being applied **first**, then the rewrite engine loops, and then the 2nd rule (the redirect rule) won't get applied because the URI has been rewritten to `/index.php` and that causes the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to fail, since `index.php` exists, thus, the redirect never happens.